# Update existing contact with image in Android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, google-contacts-api, contactscontract

I am able to update image in contact from my app and its visible in contacts but as soon as google sync occurs it deletes the image from contact.

My code:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, lRawContactId)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_PRIMARY, 1)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, 
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO,
               getImageByteArray(bitmap))
    .build());
```

Comment: i think after updating the image you need to send one message to google server that image has been updated

Comment: i don't think so as i am updating phone number, name and image together. All fields are updating expect image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you only set the thumbnail of the photo. Please see my response in [Changing contact's image to a large photo via PHOTO_FILE_ID in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855859/changing-contacts-image-to-a-large-photo-via-photo-file-id-in-android/36946702#36946702) to see how you should add or update a contact photo.